# Ajax and Jquery - Success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using Ajax to call a php site, but I want to do something "on success" and "on error".

By now, this is my js:

```
$("#votePositive").click(function(){
            var idEntrada = $('.entry').attr('id');
            var url = "{{ path('moderar_entrada_votacion') }}";
            var eleccion=1;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url, 
                data: {
                   idEntrada: idEntrada,
                   eleccion: eleccion
                },error: function(){alert("eee")}, success: function(){alert("bbb")}
            });  
        });
```

So this is my php code (just a return, just want to try if the connection works)

```
return true
```

But my site popups the alert "eee".

I've tried to:

```
return false
```

But same is happening, eee alert is comming up.

If I just remove the "return" statment from the php file, it shows up the "bbb" alert.

How can I deal with those returns? How can I tell Ajax that it went OK or Not?

Comment: Your php script should be printing values, not "returning"  What is returned to the ajax call is the http response.  The data is the body of the response which is whatever you echo on that page.  One thing that would probably help is if you set the datatype in the ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not to do with returning `true` or `false` from your PHP. Instead it's about the HTTP response code and content returned. For example, if your PHP is to simply:

```
echo 'Hello world'
```

`success` will be called. Although you will of course want to return (probably a JSON representation of) your actual dataset.

Comment: So I guess I've to play with "if i return anything, its working well" otherwise, if I don't return anything, it means that something went wrong.

Comment: Usually, if you are deciding that an error has occurred, you should return this as an HTTP error code using [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), or as content. It's common to return JSON similar to `{error: true, message: "Something was wrong"}`

Comment: Oh. Well atm I've this:`return new Response(true, 400);` or `return false;` This is working =)

Comment: I still worry you're not entirely understanding this. [Here is a VERY crude example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VadVZR) of a common approach to returning data or an error.